# "return" in optix function

Tags: gpu, nvidia, optix

I read some examples of optix SDK. And I find that there isn't any "return" in optix raygen or closethit function. Is it just a coincidence? Does "return" have a special role in optix raygen or closethit function?

I want to know why there isn't any "return" in optix raygen or closethit function.

Comment: The absence of return in raygen and closesthit is not a coincidence. It is a design choice made to fit with the unique [architecture and workflow](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/optix/optix_quickstart.htm)